# RealmObjectSchema cannot resolve by Realm 0.85.1

Tags: android, realm

I followed `Realm` Migration example on GitHub to add a Class to existing Realm Schema but its not working.

[image: RealmObjectSchema]

Comment: I think the example you saw is on master and you are using a Realm release v0.85.1? The example is for Realm's new migration system, and when saw it, it was not released yet. After you see my comment, it probably will be released at that time. Otherwise you can 1. wait a couple of hours, or 2. compile from master by yourself. :)

Comment: Alright I prefer to wait for couple of hours. ;)